# A question about continuity in seminormed vector space.

Tags: functional-analysis

> let $(V, P)$ be a seminormed vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ and $W \subset V$ linear subspace. If $\phi \in W^*$, then there is $\gamma \in V^*$ s.t $\phi(x) = \gamma(x) \ \forall x \in W$

Proof

$\phi \in W^*$ i.e $\phi$ is continuous on $(W, T_p)$, especially at the origin. Hence for $\epsilon > 0, p_1, \dots , p_n \in P$ s.t $|\phi(x)| \leq 1 \ \forall x \in W$ with $p_k(x) < \epsilon$

I don't seem to remember why continuity gives us this? Can someone care to explain? I Think this is very difficult, so alot of details would be appreciated.

$W^*$ is the set of linear, continouous maps from $W \to W$. Similar for $V^*$.

Comment: Continuity (at $0$) implies that $\phi^{-1}(\{ z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant 1\}) = \{ x : \lvert \phi(x)\rvert \leqslant 1\}$ is a neighbourhood of $0$ in $W$.

Comment: I know that the preimage of a continuous map, maps open neighbourhoods to open neighbourhoods. I also know that $U(x) = \{y \in V: p_j(x-y) < \epsilon, \forall j=1,\dots,n\}$ is a neighbourhood. What confuses me is the $|\phi(x)|$, why it comes in the Picture. @DanielFischer

Comment: It's because $\phi$ is the function we are talking about the continuity of. $|\phi(x)| \le 1$ expresses that $\phi(x)$ is in the unit disk of the base field $\Bbb F$.

Comment: I Think what I am missing is the definition of continuity in a seminormed vector space. So with $\phi : W^* \to W^*$ what is the definition of continuity in Words of seminorms? @Berci